# Passing regexp_replace matches into arguments

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a set of strings in a database which describe calculations like this:

```
"#id1# = #id2# + #id3#"
```

and a table with the ids like this:

```
ID     Human_friendly_name
id1    Name1
id2    Name2
id3    Name3
```

I'd like to substitute the human-friendly names in for the #id# format, giving me a result of:

```
Name1 = Name2 + Name3
```

The calculations do not have a limit on how many variables they can include - some are in the hundreds

One potential way to do this would be to split the equation into multiple rows (using a recursive trim, for example), do a lookup for the names and then use LISTAGG to recombine the strings.  But that seems overly complicated.

What I'd really like to do is use REGEXP_REPLACE to pass the matches into the argument for the replacement string, i.e.:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('My calculation string', 
               '#\d+#', 
               (select max(name) from table where id = REGEX_MATCH)
              )
```

I haven't been able to find any examples of passing the matched value into the replacement_string argument (although the SELECT part works).  Can anyone tell me how to do this, or confirm that it's impossible?

Comment: This is not really an operation that SQL is well-suited for.  The recursive method may be the best method.

Comment: Agreed on both counts.  Unfortunately, the database is what it is - I'm just trying to get the information out of it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought about it some more... Perhaps you meant something different?

Do you have a table with strings, like '#id1# = #id2# + #id3#', and you are looking for a query that will substitute 'Name1' in place of '#id1#', etc. - that is, the + sign in the string has NO meaning whatsoever, and you are simply wanting to do a string replacement based on a substitution table? So, for example, if you had another string '#id1# is better than a glass of #id2#' you would want the output 'Name1 is better than a glass of Name2'?

If so, you will need regular expressions AND a recursive process of some sort. Below I show how this can be done in Oracle versions 11.2 and higher (since I use the recursive subquery factoring introduced in 11.2).

**Input tables**:

```
Table: INPUT_STRINGS  
Columns: INP_STR

    INP_STR
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    #id1# = #id2# + #id3# + #id1# / #id3#
    Let #id2# be equal to #id4# - 5 + #id1##id2#


Table: HUMAN_READABLE
Columns: ID, HUMAN_READABLE_NAME

    ID                   HUMAN_READABLE_NAME
    -------------------- -----------------------------
    id1                  James Bond
    id2                  cat$5FISH
    id3
    id4                  star
```

**Query**:

```
with t (input_str, temp_str, ct) as (
       select inp_str, inp_str, regexp_count(inp_str, '#') from input_strings
       union all
       select input_str, regexp_replace(temp_str, '#[^#]*#', 
              (select human_readable_name from human_readable 
               where regexp_substr(temp_str, '#[^#]*#') = '#'||id||'#'), 1, 1), ct - 2
       from t
       where ct != 0
     )
select t.input_str, temp_str as human_readable_str from t where ct = 0;
```

**Output**:

```
INPUT_STR                                    HUMAN_READABLE_STR
-------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------
Let #id2# be equal to #id4# - 5 + #id1##id2# Let cat$5FISH be equal to star - 5 + James Bondcat$5FISH
#id1# = #id2# + #id3# + #id1# / #id3#        James Bond = cat$5FISH +  + James Bond /
```

Comment: Yes, you're correct in this interpretation of the issue.  I'm sorry if this was unclear to begin with - I was trying to simplify a MUCH bigger picture down to the essential details for this question.
Thanks for the code - it works well and made a great launching point for me!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem.  I think the issue is with when Oracle evaluates the backreferences in regexp_replace (so instead of sending the value of \1 you are actually sending the literal string '\1').  Anyway, here is a solution using SQL modeling (I like mathguy's answer too, this is just a different approach):

First, setup your ref table holding the id=>name translations:

```
create table my_ref
(
id varchar2(50) not null primary key, 
name varchar2(50)
);

insert into my_ref (id, name) values ('id1','name1');
insert into my_ref (id, name) values ('id2','name2');
insert into my_ref (id, name) values ('id3','name3');
insert into my_ref (id, name) values ('id4','name4');
insert into my_ref (id, name) values ('id5','name5');
insert into my_ref (id, name) values ('id6','name6');
commit;
```

And the main table with a few example entries:

```
create table my_tab
(
formula varchar2(50)
);

insert into my_tab values ('#id1# = #id2# + #id3#');
insert into my_tab values ('#test# = some val    #id4#');
commit;
```

Next, a basic function to translate a single id to name (lookup function):

```
create or replace function my_ref_fn(i_id in varchar2)
return varchar2
as
    rv my_ref.name%type;
begin

    begin
        select 
        -- replace id with name, keeping spaces
        regexp_replace(i_id, '( *)#(.+)#( *)', '\1' || name || '\3')
        into rv
        from my_ref
        where id = ltrim(rtrim(trim(i_id), '#'),'#');
    exception
        when no_data_found then null;
    end;
    dbms_output.put_line('"' || i_id || '" => "' || rv || '"');
    return rv;
end;
```

And to use it, we need to use SQL modeling:

```
select formula, new_val
from my_tab
MODEL
 PARTITION BY (ROWNUM rn)
   DIMENSION BY (0 dim)
   MEASURES(formula, CAST('' AS VARCHAR2(255)) word, CAST('' AS VARCHAR(255)) new_val)
   RULES ITERATE(99) UNTIL (word[0] IS NULL)
               (word[0] = REGEXP_SUBSTR(formula[0], '( *)[^ ]+( *|$)', 1, ITERATION_NUMBER + 1)
               , new_val[0] = new_val[0] || nvl(my_ref_fn(word[0]), word[0])
               );
```

Which gives:

```
FORMULA;NEW_VAL
"#id1# = #id2# + #id3#";"name1 = name2 + name3"
"#test# = some val    #id4#";"#test# = some val    name4"
```

Comment: This solution brings up a good point. In my approach I assumed every occurrence of #something# **will** have a corresponding string in the ID column in the HUMAN_READABLE table; without that assumption, my solution in its current form will fail. It can be fixed, it's for the OP to write back if that is necessary.